# How to limit ICMP Echo requests to 5, then drop for at least 30s (if the pings stop) with iptables?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I tried it with following 2 lines

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -i $EXT -m recent --set -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -i $EXT -m recent --update --hitcount 5 --seconds 30 -j ACCEPT
```

but it doesn't seem to work, i can just ping unlimited times.

Edit: worked with changing one to drop and putting them infront of my stateful rules. (Thanks @Piotr P. Karwasz)

Comment: Both your rules are `ACCEPT` rules, probably you wanted the second one to be a `DROP` rule.